# How exactly should the items in the MEC-SPQ be rotated?

Tags: methodology, survey, spatial-cognition

citing from the usage instructions of https://academic.csuohio.edu/kneuendorf/frames/MECFull.pdf

> "The MEC-SPQ was designed for immediate assignment after media
>   exposure. Starting with instructions  how  to  fill  in  the 
>   questionnaire,  and  assuring  anonymity,  **all  process  and  state
>   variables  (attention,  involvement,  SoD,  SSM,  Spatial  Presence) 
>   should  be  presented  in randomized order**. Because of the items’
>   wording, **the Domain Specific Interest Scale has to be  implemented  as
>   a  single  block.  Mixing  these  items  with  other  scales  would 
>   overstrain participants**’  ability  to  deal  with  different  levels 
>   of  judgment.  Subsequently,  all  other  trait variables  have  to 
>   be  assessed  as  randomized  item  battery.  Finally, 
>   sociodemographics  and other variables of interest conclude the
>   MEC-SPQ."

emphasis mine.

Should all items from the process and state variables be mixed together and then rotated, or should the process and state variables be kept separate, rotated, and then presented in random order?

The implied contrast to the Domain Specific interest Scale seems to point to the former option, but that seems odd to someone who is doing this for the first time.

Comment: I have been asking myself the same question and can't come to a conclusion? Did you by any chance figure out the correct way to interchange them?